# PHP send mail function is not working on other webpages

Tags: php, email, localhost, sendmail

Something wrong with my codes?

```
<?php

 $rand_2 = "abcdefghijklmnopqeABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
 $rand_key = substr(str_shuffle($rand_2), 0, 30);


 $to = "meanlinsey@gmail.com";
 $subject = "Account Validation";
 $body = "Good Day! "."Mary Ann Linsey"."\n\n Copy this validation code below to 
 confirm your registration in Portal \n\n".$rand_key;
 $header = "From: Portal";



if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $header)){
    echo 'Message has been sent to: <strong>'.$to.'</strong>';
}else{
    echo 'something went wrong';
}

?>
```

some of my send email program is working this piece of codes is not I dont why I already configure the php.ini and send_mail.ini.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

 $rand_2 = "abcdefghijklmnopqeABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
 $rand_key = substr(str_shuffle($rand_2), 0, 30);


 $to = "meanlinsey@gmail.com";
 $subject = "Account Validation";
 $body = "Good Day! "."Mary Ann Linsey"."\n\n Copy this validation code below to 
 confirm your registration in Portal \n\n".$randn_key;


 $headers ="Reply-To: \"".$name."\" <".$email_sender.">\r\n";
$headers .="MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .="From: \"".$name."\" <".$email_sender.">\r\n";
$headers .="Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"; 



if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)){
    echo 'Message has been sent to: <strong>'.$to.'</strong>';
}else{
    echo 'something went wrong';
}
?>
```

Comment: Windows has very poor flexibility with the mailing system which is what you are facing right now! Try testing you code with Linux machines. I checked your code and it is fine, Upload it to a online hosting and test it, it shall work fine.

Comment: Thank you I already found the answer my header contain too many characters